# How to sovle the error named push is not a function error in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a newbie Angular developer. I am having a problem with the push method. It has the error `ERROR Error: this.signupForm.get(...).push is not a function`. I have made references to a lot of websites and other posts in Stackoverflow, but it doesn't work. Here is my code and I also comment which line contains the error in **app.component.ts** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ehs4j8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Please format you question accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check what is the return type of `FormGroup.get()`. There error is clear: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the below line.

The form array only has the push method, you were using form control which caused the issue!

Before:

```
hobbies: new FormControl([]),
```

After:

```
hobbies: new FormArray([]), // <- changed here
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bqtcag)